# how to make a dictionary using two lists

Tags: python, list, dictionary

so I have this code and I am trying to create a lastnames to firstnames dictionary. I have created two lists out of my original dictionary which is:

```
person_to_friends = {
    'Jay Pritchett': ['Claire Dunphy', 'Gloria Pritchett', 'Manny Delgado'], 
    'Claire Dunphy': ['Jay Pritchett', 'Mitchell Pritchett', 'Phil Dunphy'], 
    'Manny Delgado': ['Gloria Pritchett', 'Jay Pritchett', 'Luke Dunphy'], 
    'Mitchell Pritchett': ['Cameron Tucker', 'Claire Dunphy', 'Luke Dunphy'], 
    'Alex Dunphy': ['Luke Dunphy'],
    'Cameron Tucker': ['Gloria Pritchett', 'Mitchell Pritchett'], 
    'Haley Gwendolyn Dunphy': ['Dylan D-Money', 'Gilbert D-Cat'],
    'Phil Dunphy': ['Claire Dunphy', 'Luke Dunphy'],
    'Dylan D-Money': ['Chairman D-Cat', 'Haley Gwendolyn Dunphy'], 
    'Gloria Pritchett': ['Cameron Tucker', 'Jay Pritchett', 'Manny Delgado'], 
    'Luke Dunphy': ['Alex Dunphy', 'Manny Delgado', 'Mitchell Pritchett', 'Phil Dunphy']
}

family_dictionary = []
friends_dictionary = []
last_names = []
for person in person_to_friends:
    family_dictionary.append(person)
    for name in person_to_friends[person]:
        friends_dictionary.append(name)
```

The above code gives me two lists, and I'm trying to use these to create a lastnames_to_firstnames dictionary where the keys are the lastnames of the people and the values should be all the names of the people with this lastname. I'm not sure how to proceed from here.

Comment: A sample of the desired output(s) would improve this question a lot!!!

Comment: Are your names always as simple as shown here, with a single space between first name and last name and no other whitespace?

Comment: You could try splitting each string by a space in your family and friends lists and mapping them to each other. Also your variable names are very confusing as `family_dictionary` and `friends_dictionary` are lists not dictionaries

Comment: So you now have two lists of names; why not make it **one** list (or even just a set, to eliminate duplicates)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to create two separate lists to solve your problem. You can do this working with the original. Here's what you'd need to do, in this order:

1. Extract all names from your dictionary
2. Remove duplicates
3. Iterate over each name, split into first and last names, and populate a dictionary

---

```
from itertools import chain

n = {}    
for v in set(chain.from_iterable([k ] + v for k, v in person_to_friends.items())):
     f, l = v.rsplit(None, 1)
     n.setdefault(l, []).append(f)
```

```
print(n)

{
    "Delgado": [
        "Manny"
    ],
    "D-Cat": [
        "Chairman",
        "Gilbert"
    ],
    "Dunphy": [
        "Claire",
        "Alex",
        "Haley Gwendolyn",
        "Phil",
        "Luke"
    ],
    "D-Money": [
        "Dylan"
    ],
    "Tucker": [
        "Cameron"
    ],
    "Pritchett": [
        "Gloria",
        "Mitchell",
        "Jay"
    ]
}
```

Here, `person_to_friends` is your input. You can also use `collections.defaultdict` object instead of a `dict` with `setdefault`. I use `itertools.chain` to flatten your dictionary. Makes the rest of the process simpler.

---

As mentioned, this is how you'd use a `defaultdict` to your advantage.

```
from collections import defaultdict

n = defaultdict(list)
for v in set(chain.from_iterable([k ] + v for k, v in person_to_friends.items())):
     f, l = v.rsplit(None, 1)
     n[l].append(f)
```

This happens to be slightly more efficient than `dict` + `setdefault`.

Comment: i cant import anything so is there a way around that?

Comment: @AbbyLiu Use `for v in set(y for x in ([k ] + v for k, v in d.items()) for y in x)` as the for loop declaration.

Answer (score 0):

If your strings are formatted `<FirstName> <LastName>` or `<FirstName> <Middle> <LastName>` and are only separated by spaces, you should check out the [split function.](https://www.mkyong.com/python/python-how-to-split-a-string/)

Answer (score 0):

You can try this;

```
from collections import defaultdict
import itertools
d = defaultdict(list)
person_to_friends = {'Jay Pritchett': ['Claire Dunphy', 'Gloria Pritchett', 'Manny Delgado'], 
'Claire Dunphy': ['Jay Pritchett', 'Mitchell Pritchett', 'Phil Dunphy'], 
'Manny Delgado': ['Gloria Pritchett', 'Jay Pritchett', 'Luke Dunphy'], 
'Mitchell Pritchett': ['Cameron Tucker', 'Claire Dunphy', 'Luke Dunphy'], 
'Alex Dunphy': ['Luke Dunphy'],
'Cameron Tucker': ['Gloria Pritchett', 'Mitchell Pritchett'], 
'Haley Gwendolyn Dunphy': ['Dylan D-Money', 'Gilbert D-Cat'],
'Phil Dunphy': ['Claire Dunphy', 'Luke Dunphy'],
'Dylan D-Money': ['Chairman D-Cat', 'Haley Gwendolyn Dunphy'], 
'Gloria Pritchett': ['Cameron Tucker', 'Jay Pritchett', 'Manny Delgado'], 
'Luke Dunphy': ['Alex Dunphy', 'Manny Delgado', 'Mitchell Pritchett', 'Phil Dunphy']
}
new_people = list(itertools.chain.from_iterable([[i.split() for i in [a]+b] for a, b in person_to_friends.items()]))
for i in new_people:
   d[i[-1]].append(i[0])

final_list = {a:list(set(b)) for a, b in d.items()}
```

Output:

```
{'Dunphy': ['Alex', 'Luke', 'Claire', 'Phil', 'Haley'], 'D-Money': ['Dylan'], 'Tucker': ['Cameron'], 'D-Cat': ['Gilbert', 'Chairman'], 'Delgado': ['Manny'], 'Pritchett': ['Mitchell', 'Gloria', 'Jay']}
```

Without importing anything:

```
d = {}
new_people = [[i.split() for i in [a]+b] for a, b in person_to_friends.items()]
for listing in new_people:
    for i in listing:
        if i[-1] in d:
           d[i[-1]].append(i[0])
        else:
           d[i[-1]] = [i[0]]

d = {a:list(set(b)) for a, b in d.items()}
```

Output:

```
{'Dunphy': ['Alex', 'Luke', 'Claire', 'Phil', 'Haley'], 'D-Money': ['Dylan'], 'Tucker': ['Cameron'], 'D-Cat': ['Gilbert', 'Chairman'], 'Delgado': ['Manny'], 'Pritchett': ['Mitchell', 'Gloria', 'Jay']}
```

Comment: is there anyway to do this without importing anything

Answer (score 0):

As you said you have two requirement :

> i cant import anything so is there a way around that?
>
> the keys are the lastnames of the people and the values should be all
>   the names of the people with this lastname.

Here is without any import approach :

```
person_to_friends = {
    'Jay Pritchett': ['Claire Dunphy', 'Gloria Pritchett', 'Manny Delgado'],
    'Claire Dunphy': ['Jay Pritchett', 'Mitchell Pritchett', 'Phil Dunphy'],
    'Manny Delgado': ['Gloria Pritchett', 'Jay Pritchett', 'Luke Dunphy'],
    'Mitchell Pritchett': ['Cameron Tucker', 'Claire Dunphy', 'Luke Dunphy'],
    'Alex Dunphy': ['Luke Dunphy'],
    'Cameron Tucker': ['Gloria Pritchett', 'Mitchell Pritchett'],
    'Haley Gwendolyn Dunphy': ['Dylan D-Money', 'Gilbert D-Cat'],
    'Phil Dunphy': ['Claire Dunphy', 'Luke Dunphy'],
    'Dylan D-Money': ['Chairman D-Cat', 'Haley Gwendolyn Dunphy'],
    'Gloria Pritchett': ['Cameron Tucker', 'Jay Pritchett', 'Manny Delgado'],
    'Luke Dunphy': ['Alex Dunphy', 'Manny Delgado', 'Mitchell Pritchett', 'Phil Dunphy']
}

last_names=["".join(i.split()[-1:]) for i in person_to_friends]
lastnames_to_firstnames ={}
for key,items in person_to_friends.items():
    for last_name in last_names:
        for names in items:
            if last_name in names:
                if last_name not in lastnames_to_firstnames :
                    lastnames_to_firstnames[last_name]=[names]
                else:
                    if names not in lastnames_to_firstnames .get(last_name):
                        lastnames_to_firstnames[last_name].append(names)

print(lastnames_to_firstnames)
```

output:

```
{'D-Money': ['Dylan D-Money'], 'Tucker': ['Cameron Tucker'], 'Pritchett': ['Gloria Pritchett', 'Mitchell Pritchett', 'Jay Pritchett'], 'Dunphy': ['Haley Gwendolyn Dunphy', 'Alex Dunphy', 'Phil Dunphy', 'Claire Dunphy', 'Luke Dunphy'], 'Delgado': ['Manny Delgado']}
```